# Setting the Homepage URL in Craft 3

Tags: siteurl, craft3

This seems like an odd question, but I've looked through the documentation, Slack, and the StackExchange and it's weird that I'm not seeing anything... so I feel like I'm overcomplicating it.

How do you set a Single (or anything for that matter) to be the homepage of a Craft 3 site? In Craft 2 there was the "This is for the homepage" option, but I don't see that in Craft 3. Is that because it hasn't been implemented yet or is there a new best practice for doing this? Is this going to be something added into `Setting > Sites` section?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it seems the way to do this is actually by leaving the slug blank. If you happen to look down on the section setup screen prior to naming your section you'll see it clearly: `Leave blank if this is the homepage.` However since that field is automatically filled in with details from the Name/Handle fields I never actually saw the text by the time I was down there unless I completely cleared the field out.

Both fields need to remain empty from what I can tell, not just the slug.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried changing the slug of the page to "__home__" (without quotes)?

Comment: I hadn't. While this didn't work, removing the existing slug to try it lead me to my answer which I'll post about shortly.

Answer (score 1):

A little more useful detail possibly, is here:  https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/1502